# Is the i in kakikonde silent?

Tags: pronunciation

Here's the sentence that I was listening to: Kono shorui ni Yan-san no juusho, shimei, seinengappi nado o **kakikonde** kudasai. When I was listening to it, it sounded like the word was being pronounced as: kakonde. Obviously, I didn't hear the i or ki. But still is the i silent or am I not just hearing it right?

Secondary questions: 1) why shimei and not namae? 2) what is the konde in kakikonde?

http://youtu.be/qBh5ru-4AHw?t=10m16s

Comment: Answers to your secondary questions : 1) [What's the difference in usage between 氏名 (しめい) and 名前 (なまえ)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/689/542). And 2) [What does -komu (ー込む) at the end of a word mean?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45/542)

Comment: You should have made this an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Between voiceless consonants, u and i sounds often become silent. The most notable example is the ending ました or ます in verbs. In the case of *kakikonde* 書き込んで it would be *kak-konde*, with very light *i* sound, not *kakonde* like you said.

氏名 *shimei* refers to 氏 and 名, which combine to mean "full name". On the other hand 名前 is often use to indicate the "given name".

More about this on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicelessness

> Sonorants are those sounds, such as vowels and nasals, which are voiced in most of the world's languages. However, in some languages sonorants may be voiceless, usually allophonically. For example, the Japanese word sukiyaki is pronounced [su̥kijaki]. This may sound like [skijaki] to an English speaker, but the lips can be seen compressing for the [u̥].

Comment: I usually hear the "silent i" as something like [[ç](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal_fricative)]...